# How to parse array json in Go?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have the following JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "960.094", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "438149000.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "15587054083.0", 
        "available_supply": "16234925.0", 
        "total_supply": "16234925.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.76", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-7.78", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-14.39", 
        "last_updated": "1490393946"
    }
]
```

And I have two struct:

```
type Valute struct {
    Id     string `json:"id"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Symbol string `json:"symbol"`
}

type Currency struct {
    Result []Valute
}
```

I want to parse the array returned by this call:

```
resp, err := http.Get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=1")
defer resp.Body.Close()
v := Currency{}
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
json.Unmarshal(body, &v)
```

But it does not work for me. Currency is empty.

It works with an array:

```
var valutes []Valute
json.Unmarshal(body, &valutes)
```

But I want to use a struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Currency struct simply has to implement the [json.Unmarshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface.

```
func (c *Currency) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(b, &c.Result)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just change to `json.Unmarshal(body, &v.Result)`